# ng-grid cell click event callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid and trying to set a callback for when a cell gets clicked. In that callback, I want to know the row and column of the cell. The best way I found is to use cellTemplate (and put an onclick event) in columnDefs **for each column**, which is not very DRY:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name',
                  cellTemplate: '<div onclick="...">{{row.entity[col.field]}}</div>'
                  },
                  {field: 'age', displayName: 'Age', cellTemplate: ...}
                ]
};
```

This is problematic too, since ng-click doesn't work, and I can't use the controller's scope with onclick..

Non ng-grid solutions are welcome too..

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, ng-grid doesn't have a very good concept of returning the column number.

If you can get by with just row number, the below plunker should show you how to do it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jYZWV9FpCdeENIETLEXV?p=preview

You use the beforeSelectionChange function, which includes the rowItem. That has the row number and such.

The other option is to use the cell template to add a data attribute to every cell with the row/column number, then setup an event listener for the click even on that. If's still using a lot of columnDefs and own't be very DRY, but it will be a bit more DRY than what you've got now.